# IIS URL Rewrite for NX Angular Monorepo

Tags: angular, iis, web-config, windows-server, monorepo

I have a structure of projects created with nx and angular and they work without any problem.

[image]

I work with windows servers and use IIS, everything works correctly up to a certain point since I had to configure the iis as follows

[image]

Each route enters a module other than a default route (each route has the same structure) and everything works fine up to here, the problem occurs until I try to enter query params and I can't get the url to open the angular route to which I want to reach directly. I have already tried localhost and the redirection works perfectly, I just think it is a problem with the web config and the route mapping.

if I enter the path:

http://www.monorepoapp.com/information-technology/inventory/d649bab6-fe3b-4289-9d06-86bbb05e4ec3?id=63&type=in-progress

I get http://www.monorepoapp.com/information-technology/

I have already tried to create a rule before "IT Route" that specifically reads the url with parameters but they all show a not found error

Comment: You can help yourself by enabling FRT to learn more about the errors, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: As mentioned at the end in the description of your question, will this routing rule work locally? Maybe you can check if [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52538173/angular-router-removes-query-params-when-deployed-on-iis-server) helps you if it works correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I finally gave up on the redirection from the web config and implemented the redirection from the application itself. Since within each module the redirection worked correctly, the problem was that when entering the notification from a different module the screen did not load at all. I will try to explain the solution I found in case someone else has the same problem